# Allow user to import a file from a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

From what I can gather this does not even seem possible but here goes:

I am finishing up a Greasemonkey script. In this script the end user is able to save certain things to an html5 `localStorage` variable (not the purpose of the script, only for one part of it).

Since a cache clear can wipe these storage values I have created an export feature which is simply an unknown datatype which forces a download of the file.

```
data:something;charset=utf-8,'+encodeURIComponent(somevariable)
```

My question is on creating an import feature. Since the file saves with no extension and this script will be used exclusively in Linux, opening the file directly in a text program and pasting the data into a textarea would be an easy way to import.

However, is there any way without some sort of server-side scripting or external server to let the user choose a file to import? 
Such as a dialog box that allows the end-user to select the file from the computer in which I can then manipulate from my end?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ . Also, you don't need to use data-urls, you can use Blobs directly

Comment: You should post this as the answer because you have answered it and I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 introduces the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

> Using the File API, which was added to the DOM in HTML5, it's now possible for web content to ask the user to select local files, then read the contents of those files. This selection can be done by either using an HTML  element, or by drag and drop.

You can hook on `change` events and check  `evt.target.files;`

Also, you can use Blobs to handle your data, you don't have to rely on data uris.

Here is [a good tutorial about it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 File API to the rescue!

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Not supported in IE9, but most modern browser do support it :
http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Luckily this will be used by all intended users exclusively in chrome and firefox with newest updates.